# Why was this Twin-Otter Take-Off unsuccessful?

Tags: takeoff

Watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLiZBsbWv-0) I was asking myself, what was the error or cause of this unsuccessful take-off?

Comment: the video has some comments under it, which seem to explain what was wrong in this take off

Comment: Simple: the pilots did not do their pre-flight calculations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments under the video say clearly:

According to Transportation Safety Board (Canada) report # AO7W0128,

1. Take-off weight did not meet performance capabilities of the Aircraft.
2. Calculations to clear 50ft obstacle were not performed.
3. Southeast end of runway, not clearly marked.
4. Take-off was attempted in an up slope direction with a slight tailwind which increased the necessary distance to clear a 50ft obstacle.
5. Center of gravity (CG) calculations were off and found to be too far forward.

Comment: You might add that the pilot tried to rotate too early (twice), instead of letting speed build up to proper rotation speed.

Comment: In the [official report](http://www.bst-tsb.gc.ca/eng/rapports-reports/aviation/2007/a07w0128/a07w0128.asp), I do not see a mention of the pilot rotating too early.

Comment: It can be seen in the video. An then the plane lifts one wing, while the other is stalled - because the pilot tried to rotate with inadequate speed.

Comment: One is at about 1:44, where he rotates far enough to lift the front wheel clean up